# CoCreateInstance hangs when called from OnThreadCreate

Tags: c++, multithreading, com, directshow, virtual-webcam

I have a problem with CoCreateInstance which doesn't ever return after being called. Its called from a overriden method of CSourceStream::OnThreadCreate

I think the problem is that I try to use COM inside a seperate thread but I am not sure. How do I use COM inside another thread? Here is the call stack and how I call the function anyways. I checked that CoInitialiseEx returns S_FALSE, so com is running on that thread.
[image: Call Stack]

```cpp
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pGraph));
```

I found out that if I use CoCreateInstance in another method(CSourceStream::FillBuffer) that runs on the same thread it works but I don't know why.

When CoCreateInstance hangs, its stuck on WaitForMultipleObjectsEx, like so:
[image: Call stack 2]

Comment: My crystal ball says you didn't call `CoInitializeEx` on that thread.

Comment: Not to be rude, but did you read my question? I did call CoInitializeEx and it returns S_FALSE - (from msdn S_FALSE = The COM library is already initialized on this thread.).

Comment: More info here: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is probably not a COM issue by itself. Read Filter Graph Manager's doc carefully, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/filter-graph-manager it has some threading subtleties. COM is running, but maybe not the way it should.

Answer (score 0):

Like Simon said in the comments, changing `CLSID_FilterGraph` to `CLSID_FilterGraphNoThread` removed the deadlock.